# Sticky Footer in Alloy

Tags: titanium, scrollview, tableview, titanium-alloy, tss

Is there such as a sticky footer table in Alloy?

I'm trying to do something Like instagrams sticky header view but I want the footer to be the sticky part?

any ideas how to achieve this?

Since some people didn't understand the question

What I meant is does titanium support zindex on scrollable views? I have 3 views A,B,C and I want to scroll B over A(keep bottom of A visible) and then C over B(keep bottom of C visible)?

Thanks[image]

Comment: yes both scrollView and scrollableView supports zIndex.

Comment: Do you know if the mentioned behaviour is used using nested scrollableviews with different Z index?

Answer (score 1):

```
<View class="container" >
  <View class="mainView"/>
  <View class="bottomView"/>
</View>
```

//tss is

```
".container":{}
".mainView":{width:Ti.UI.FILL, height: Ti.UI.FILL, bottom:50dp}
".bottomView":{bottom:0,height:50dp}
```

Make sure you have Added bottom:50 to mainView.

Comment: What I meant is does titanium support zindex on scrollable views? I have 3 views A B C and I want to scroll B over A and then C over B? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

sure. You just create a view with bootom:0 and a height. That will stick to the bottom. All your other elements go into a scrollable view that lays below the footer view. E.g.

index.xml

```
<ScrollView id="content"/>
<View id="bottom"/>
```

index.tss

```
"#content":{top:0,bottom:40,left:0,right:0,backgroundColor:"yellow"}
"#bottom":{bottom:0,height:40,left:0,right:0,backgroundColor:"blue"}
```

Comment: What I meant is does titanium support zindex on scrollable views? I have 3 views A B C and I want to scroll B over A and then C over B? 
Thanks

Comment: yes, its called zIndex (http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-property-zIndex). But it will also take the position inside your XML in account (later views are on top of another). But you can also set zIndex

Comment: So what you're proposing is to have a scrollview and within it 3 scroll views nested? is this possible?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how it would look like. Could you add an image that shows what you want,please. You want one footer or two? Or a footer for each scrollview? You initial question was one sticky footer now you have 3 views which is a bit confusing

Comment: I've added a picture that describes the desired output.